# Documentation for the SqlUnitTesting_VS2013 config file

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

Is anyone aware of where to find the documentation for the app.config section for database unit tests in Visual Studio 2013?

i.e. the documentation for:

```
<section name="SqlUnitTesting_VS2013" type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Configuration.SqlUnitTestingSection, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where is the documentation about these config attributes. Check my question here [SSDT Unit Test:. An error occurred while SQL Server unit testing settings were being read from the configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896611/ssdt-unit-test-an-error-occurred-while-sql-server-unit-testing-settings-were-b)

I came up with my own app.config (after lots of research and try&error) and it is working. Your database project need to deploy in order to make the tests run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.data.localdb" type="System.Data.LocalDBConfigurationSection,System.Data,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <section name="SqlUnitTesting_VS2013" type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Configuration.SqlUnitTestingSection, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </configSections>
  <system.data.localdb>
    <localdbinstances>
      <add name="(localdb)\ProjectsV12" version="12.0" />
    </localdbinstances>
  </system.data.localdb>
  <SqlUnitTesting_VS2013>
    <DatabaseDeployment DatabaseProjectFileName="..\..\..\Database_Project_Name\Database_Project_Name.sqlproj"
        Configuration="Debug" />
    <DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
    <ExecutionContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30"
        CommandTimeout="30" />
    <PrivilegedContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30"
        CommandTimeout="30" />
  </SqlUnitTesting_VS2013>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Ebeid, good work! Unfortunately I'm not working on that sort of thing anymore so unable to test it out, but I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Note that if, like me, you're trying to get it working on a build server, the Build Server override should contain *only* the SqlUnitTesting section, not the whole config file!